# NPE when obtaining KeyStore instance

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, pkcs#12

I have this simple code that was working a while back. Basically I am trying to get the keystore instance so that I can use it to enable ssl.
My problem now is I get the null pointer exception below and can't seem to find a solution anywhere.
I use openjdk 8 on ubuntu 15.04 32 bit.

```
//Do other initializations things
...
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

char[] keymanagerPassPhrase = keymanagerPassPhraseString.toCharArray();
char[] keystorePassPhrase = keystorePassPhraseString.toCharArray();
char[] truststorePassPhrase = truststorePassPhraseString.toCharArray();

ks.load(new FileInputStream(keystoreFile), keystorePassPhrase);

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
kmf.init(ks, keymanagerPassPhrase);

TrustManager[] trustManagers = null;
    if( useCustomTrustStore ) {
         ts.load(new FileInputStream(truststoreFile), truststorePassPhrase);

         TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            tmf.init(ts);

         trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();
        }
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(protocal);

        sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustManagers , null);

        return sslContext.createSSLEngine();
```

The exception thrown is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.security.Provider$ServiceKey.<init>(Provider.java:872)
at java.security.Provider$ServiceKey.<init>(Provider.java:865)
at java.security.Provider.getService(Provider.java:1039)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getService(ProviderList.java:332)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:157)
at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)
at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:848)
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: set breakpoints at the lines where you call getInstance

Comment: @CS I don't get you. Please explain, do you mean ; or what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Q's a little old but near the top of the Google results for this problem, so I'll try to help.

To debug a NPE in Java's codebase, you just need to make sure you have the Java source code available in your IDE; then you can check for a hint on what is null.  You seem to be using JDK 8, so it's this line:

```
algorithm = algorithm.toUpperCase(ENGLISH);
```

Plus, there's nothing else in the ServiceKey init method (constructor) that could cause a NPE.  So... where does the `String algorithm` parameter come from, passed into this constructor?

It looks like it's just passed through all of these layers; see `at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)` -- algorithm is the first param passed in there.

Unwrap one more: `at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:848)` -- the param you pass in here is called "type", but that's what's passed into `Security.getImpl` as `algorithm`.

So the bug is that you're passing null for the `type` param when you call `KeyStore.getInstance()`.  This doesn't seem to match up with the source code you listed, so you may not have compiled your code properly.  Add in a "sanity check" -- e.g., a println earlier in your code; and see what line number in *your* code is indicated further down the stack trace.